# Pages not loading fully/correctly some times

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a site that on only certain occasions (and so far I have only seen this using Safari 4 on Mac) does not load a page correctly, so the underlying HTML code shows up. Have been unable to find any information about this on the net, not sure what could be causing it...

The setup is:
- Rails app
- Phusion Passenger 
- Nginx 
- html doctype strict
-prototype 
- jquery noconflict
- flowplayer
- facebox, 
- soundmanager
- webfaction

Comment: Do you have anything that can help diagnose this problem, such as a comparison to the behaviour of Firefox or Chrome, or a screenshot?

Comment: Need more info, but my guess is that in one controller action that handles responds both js and html, and is returning the js block, when you are expecting html

Comment: Quick pointer is that the only reason your html text would show up like that is if it wasn't included in a body tag.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough about this problem. What’s happening more specifically is the page is rendering mostly correctly, but then there will be one tiny bit of code that apparently does not get sent or read, so that a small portion of the code seems to show up....

Answer (score 0):

There must be a conflict of the code so that the browser thinks the code has ended and its reading text. This could be caused by ' being the styled type or a hundred other things. Please provide the generate code of the page for us to review.

Comment: I hope Gordon has this fixed by now.